# Background disappears with any additional position, size, etc code, but is visible without

Tags: html, css

I'm using the following code for a header image (that changes to a different image on mobile, which may be the main issue)

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
.header-background {
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    background-color:#000000;
    background:url(http://matsushiro.org/new/tunnel-header3.png);
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.header-background {
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    background-color:#000000;
    background:url(http://matsushiro.org/new/tunnel-header-mobile.png);
}
```

}

The code is for a div used as the header and if possible I want it to take up the whole viewport. The problem is at the moment the image is really big, of course (see here on desktop: http://matsushiro.org/new/). So I'm trying to resize it using "contain" (or any other method, it doesn't really matter), but whenever I change anything at all about background - size, position, etc, whether it's in line with the background:url line or separately as background-size:, the background completely disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited:

Since your class attributes are the same you can refactor your css to:

```
.header-background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #000000;
  background-image: url(http://matsushiro.org/new/tunnel-header3.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: contain;
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    background-image: url(http://matsushiro.org/new/tunnel-header-mobile.png);
  }
}
```

Also: you can optimize much more that PNG image just by exporting as png-8 16 colours in Photoshop.

Have fun!

Comment: Hi, sorry looks like that was my copy-paste error, I've fixed it now.

Comment: Finally had time to come back to this - it worked, thanks a bunch :). I'll change the image to png-8 too.

Answer (score 0):

add this line to your css

```
background-size: cover;
```

i tried it on your site in chrome console and the background didn't disappeared.
try reloading with `ctrl+f5` maybe it could help you

Comment: Hi, sorry looks like that was my copy-paste error, I've fixed it now.

Comment: Tried this - I'm not sure why it's working in your Chrome but not mine, but it's not working in my Chrome or Safari